# disable click on hover

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery game that my members keep finding ways to win. It's the numbers game here [link text](http://gamerholic.com/pan.php).

I've made the game so you can't play it on firefox, don't know if other browsers have the same cheat tools as firefox.

1st problem I had was gamers would just keep their mouse over one box till their number showed up then they'd click it. To fix that (with some help from a genius on stackoverflow) we made it so you can't click the same box twice in a row. 
But now it's the same problem, they'll just move to another box and keep their mouse their till they see their number. So now I need to make it so if they over over a box for more than x number of seconds they won't be able to click on that box.

A count down timer may just do the trick though and eliminate the hover script. Please help with which ever one you can. Here's the script.

```
    var hitCount = 0,
missCount = 0;

function IsNumeric(n) {
return !isNaN(n);
}

$("#getit").click(function() {
var hitCount = 0,
missCount = 0;
$('#misscount').text(0);
$('#hitcount').text(0);
$('#message').hide(100);        
$('#randomnumber').empty();
$('#randomnumber').show(300);       
var li = [],
    intervals = 0,
    n = parseInt($('#MyNumber').val());

if (IsNumeric(n)) {
   intervalId= setInterval(function() {
        li[intervals++ % li.length].text(Math.random() > .1 ? Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 + n) + (n / 2)) : n).attr('class', '')    ;
    }, <?php echo $time ?>);
}

$('#randomnumber').empty();

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    li.push($('<li />').one('click', function() {
        BoxClick.call(this, n);
    }).appendTo('#randomnumber'));
}


function BoxClick(n) {
var $this = $(this);
$('#randomnumber li').unbind().one('click', function() {
        BoxClick.call(this,n);
});
$this.unbind();

if (!$this.hasClass('clicked')) {
    if (parseInt($this.text(), 10) === n) {
        $this.addClass('correct');
        $('#hitcount').text(++hitCount);
    } else {
        $this.addClass('wrong');
        $('#misscount').text(++missCount);
    }
}
            if(missCount==<?php echo $limit ?>){
               clearInterval(intervalId);
               $('#randomnumber').hide(300);

                $.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : 'FBhighscore_hwnd.php',
dataType : 'json',
data: {
tgameid: $('#tgameid').val(),MyNumber: $('#MyNumber').val(),totalHits: hitCount
},
success : function(data){
$('#waiting').hide(500);
$('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
.text(data.msg).show(500);
if (data.error === true)
$('#loginForm').show(500);
else
$('#send').hide(500);       
},
error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
$('#waiting').hide(500);
$('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
.text('There was an error.').show(500);
$('#loginForm').show(500);
}
});

            }


$this.addClass('clicked');
}
return false;
});
```

Comment: *"I've made the game so you can't play it on firefox, don't know if other browsers have the same cheat tools as firefox."* Yes. **Nothing** client-side can be trusted, it can **all** be faked. Anything you receive from the client, you must validate on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily remember when they stared hovering. Using a simplified example of a span with the ID "container" containing spans the user would click on:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var container, n;
  var HOVER_THRESHOLD = 1000; // Milliseconds

  // Build the grid
  container = $('#container');
  for (n = 0; n < 16; ++n) {
    $("<span>0</span>").appendTo(container).data("hoverStart", 0);
  }

  // Watch for hovers and clicks on the elements
  container.find('span')
    .hover(startHover, stopHover)
    .click(handleClick);

  // At hover start, remember when we started
  function startHover() {
    $(this).data("hoverStart", new Date().getTime());
  }

  // At hover end, clear the hover thingy
  function stopHover() {
    $(this).data("hoverStart", 0);
  }

  // On click, check how long they've been hovering
  function handleClick() {
    var $this, startHover;

    $this = $(this);
    startHover = $this.data("hoverStart");

    // Hovering too long?
    if (startHover != 0
        && (new Date().getTime() - startHover) > HOVER_THRESHOLD) {
      // Yes
      $this.css("color", "red");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $this.css("color", "");
      }, 500);
    }
    else {
      // No, allow click
      $this.html(parseInt($this.html(), 10) + 1);
    }
  }
});​
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uveku3)

Or you can do the more complex (but proactive) thing with timers:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var container, n;
  var HOVER_THRESHOLD = 1000; // Milliseconds

  // Build the grid
  container = $('#container');
  for (n = 0; n < 16; ++n) {
    $("<span>0</span>").appendTo(container).data("hoverTimer", 0);
  }

  // Watch for hovers and clicks on the elements
  container.find('span')
    .hover(startHover, stopHover)
    .click(handleClick);

  // At hover start, start a timer
  function startHover() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data("hoverTimer", setTimeout(function() {
      $this.addClass("disabled");
    }, HOVER_THRESHOLD));
  }

  // At hover end, clear the timer
  function stopHover() {
    var $this, timer;

    $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass("disabled"); // May or may not have it
    timer = $this.data("hoverTimer");
    if (timer != 0) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      $this.data("hoverTimer", 0);
    }
  }

  // On click, check how long they've been hovering
  function handleClick() {
    var $this;

    $this = $(this);

    // Hovering too long?
    if ($this.hasClass("disabled")) {
      // Yes, disallow the click
    }
    else {
      // No, allow click
      $this.html(parseInt($this.html(), 10) + 1);
      // If you want to reset the hover timer on click:
      stopHover.call(this);
      startHover.call(this);
    }
  }
});​
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uveku3/2)

But again, as I said in my comment, you can't trust *any* data sent to you by the client for this sort of thing, there are too many tools for debugging web applications (which is a great thing!) or just completely faking HTTP messages. In your case, I don't think it's *possible* to differentiate a gifted player from a gifted faker (ham-handed fakers you can probably figure out from the data).

Comment: WOW thank you very much for the great detail. I'm trying to add this to my current script now.

Comment: I've been toying with this for hours. The setInterval in my script causes the hover to reset when the script refresh, which in turn makes the block active again. This is a tough one.